# Textbox element "ruins" page layout

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

So, I have a form, which looks like this:
[image: Snapshot of the form!]
And, as you can see, the "Opis" is on the bottom, however it should be on the top. I'm trying to fix it *properly* (without using float and a fixed height) for the past hour. I'd prefer a solution which doesn't involve float elements, but if it can't be avoided I won't be too picky.

### The CSS:

```
#main {
    width: 800px;
    display: table;
}

selection {display: table-row}

section > * {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}

#main h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 110%;
    width: 130px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform:capitalize
}
#main div {
    width: 650px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

### The HTML excerpt

```
<section>
    <h3><label for="date">Datum</label></h3>
    <div><input type="text" id="date" name="datum"/></div>
</section>
<section>
    <h3><label for="vp">Vrijeme</label></h3>
    <div><input type="text" id="vp" name="vp"/><br><br><input type="text" name="vz"/></div>
</section>
<section>
    <h3>Opis</h3>
    <div><textarea name="opis" rows="5" cols="50" style="resize: none;"></textarea></div>
</section>
<section>
    <h3>Logo</h3>
    <div><select id="combobox">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
            <option value="...">...</option>
    </select></div>
</section>
```

Thanks! :D

Comment: Display the h3 and div inline-block and set vertical-align: top;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`label`s should have for property `vertical-align` a value of `top`

Please check the dabblet http://dabblet.com/gist/1574836 where I also simplified the HTML code, added for/id association for all form elements (including textarea and select) and a label for an input that hadn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code snippets posted (they are hardly a sufficient extract of the actual code, partly because the CSS code uses a class name that does not appear in the HTML code), the following would fix the problem presented:

1) Modify the markup by slapping `<div class=table>` and `</div>` around it.

2) Add the CSS code

```
.table { display: table; }
section  {display: table-row}
```

3) Change the CSS code

```
vertical-align: baseline;
```

to

```
vertical-align: top;
```

It would be much simpler and more robust to use a real HTML table, using CSS just to tune the presentation details. That way, the page would not collapse on older browsers that do not support CSS table features at all. That way, or even in the CSS table approach, you do not need to set widths in px units. Just check out first how things work without any width settings, and if some tuning is really needed, consider using the `em` unit.